# Making a summation function in r

Tags: r, function

I work with birds, and every time a bird copulates with the same female, he inseminates less sperm each time. Assuming that the first insemination is worth 80 sperm, and each posterior insemination decreases at a constant rate of 20%, I'm interested in making a simple summation function that calculates the total sperm inseminated after n copulations.

In other words, I want a function that does this: 80 + (80*0.8^1) + (80*0.8^2).... + (80*0.8^n) = x, with the arguments being number of sperm on the first copulation, the rate of loss, and the number of copulations.

Comment: You could solve this analytically, without R.

Comment: `bird_fun <- function(n, s, r) sum(rep(s, n) * (r ^ (0:(n-1))))`

Comment: `Val <- 80; P <- 0.8; N <- 2; sum(Val*P^(0:N))`